# Reactor 3.x (Java): for web scraping

Tags: java, project-reactor

Reactor noob here.

This is more of a HowTo question.

Let's say I have a website I want to scrape containing a paged set of search results.  The number of search result pages is unknown.  Each search page has a link to the next page.  I want to scrape all the search results from all pages and process each search result.

How might I use Reactor (Mono/Flux) to accomplish this in Java?

I want to do this as "reactively" as possible.

Basically, the Reactor (3.x) version of the following imperative pseudo code:

```
    String url = "http://example.com/search/1";
    Optional<Document> docOp = getNextPage(url);    (1)
    while (docOp.isPresent()) {
        Document doc = docOp.get();
        processDoc(doc);                            (2)
        docOp = getNextPage(getNextUrl(doc));       (3)
    }

    // (1) Get the first page of search results
    // (2) Process all the search results on this page asynchronously
    // (3) Find the next page URL, and get that page
```

Answer (score 0):

With some help from https://gitter.im/reactor/reactor I arrived at this solution.  It may not be ideal.  I'd love to get feedback on any problems anyone might see.

```
public void scrape() {

    Try<Document> firstDocTry = this.getSearchResultsPage(Option.<Document>none().toTry());    (1)

    // Generate a flux where each element in the flux is created using the current element
    Flux.<Try<Document>, Try<Document>>generate(() -> firstDocTry, (docTry, sink) -> {         (2)
            docTry = this.getSearchResultsPage(docTry);
            docTry.isFailure() ? sink.complete() : sink.next(docTry);
            return docTry;
        })
        .flatMap(docTry -> this.transformToScrapedLoads(docTry))                               (3)
        .log()
        .subscribe(scrapedLoad ->
            scrapedLoadRepo.save(scrapedLoad)                                                  (4)
        );
}

protected Try<Document> getSearchResultsPage(Try<Document> docTry) {
    ...
}

protected Flux<ScrapedLoad> transformToScrapedLoads(Try<Document> docTry) {
    ...
}
```

(1) Using Javaslang's monadic Try and Option here. 'firstDocTry' Seeds the generator.  getSearchResultsPage() knows to 
start at the first page of search, if no Document provided.

(2) Using a generator here.  Each element published in the Flux is determined by the prior element

(3) the transform method converts each doc to a Flux, which are combined and sent to subscribe as a single Flux

(4) The subscriber operates on each element produced by the Flux.  In this case, persisting them.